# One sqlite db per savegame or one big sqlite db for all the savegames?

Tags: android, databases, sql

when you develop a simple local game, with 4 slots for history mode, wich option is better to persist the savegame of the history slot openned by the user?

The game has 4 entities with some simple relations between them. Which whould be the best option? A single db file with all stored inside, or one db for each savegame?

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to GameDev. I haven't used SQLite in a couple of years (last time was when I also developed an android game), but I've been using MySQL on the back-end in all of my games for years and most of the principles apply to both.

My general advice would be to keep all saved games in one database and structure your database correctly (i.e. normalise it etc.). Part of my rationale here is if you are storing what would normally be stored in a "saved games" table like date_saved etc., then writing queries against this table looking for most recent saves etc. will be much easier than having to do the same thing across different databases.

Hope this helps.